# IMPORTXML and probem with XPath in Google Sheets

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web, google-sheets

I have one problem with extracting statistic to Google spreadsheets from 
http://www.sohu.com/a/224426280_100119144

I need extract 84 from 阅读 (84)
but when i use the

```
//*[@id="article-container"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span/em
```

it just gives me #N/A .
If i use only

```
//div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span
```

without /em, it gives me 阅读 (     ) without statistics,

[Still nothing, other xpath ways also gives #N/A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky0aj.png)

[can it be a problem with google spreadsheets? with XPath Helper trow any xpath ways I can find the number, but is nothing in google spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuyZo.png)

Any help someone pls?))

Comment: I can't find the number 84 anywhere in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have appended the *text()* function to your XPath:

```
//*[@id="article-container"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span/em/text()
```

After running the XPath on the website I was able to get the "87" as a result. 
Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work in google spreadsheets, I have edit the question and added some pics, that you can check, can it be some problems with a google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

I located the correct `<em>` tag and got its text, which is the number that keeps updating.

`//em[@data-role="pv"][@data-val="$articleStat.pv"]/text()`

Comment: Yes, it's a view statistic, and it keeps updating, and the correct Xpath work only in Xpath Helper App for Google Chrome, but it doesn't work in google spreadsheets...even there works another Xpath way that gives 阅读 ( )